# sessionWithConfiguration freezing iOS 8 iPhone 4S on new Xcode 6.0.1

Tags: xcode, ios8, nsurlsession

I am experiencing a disturbing issue when trying to execute one of my apps on an iPhone 4S with iOS8 and Xcode 6.0.1. What happens is that the control seems to freeze in the last instruction of the block:

```
dispatch_once(&onceToken, ^{
    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration backgroundSessionConfigurationWithIdentifier:@"myBackgroundSessionIdentifier"];
    NSLog(@"configuration=%@", configuration);
    configuration.allowsCellularAccess = YES;
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForRequest = 30.0;
    configuration.timeoutIntervalForResource = 60.0;
    configuration.HTTPMaximumConnectionsPerHost = 1;
    session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:self delegateQueue:[NSOperationQueue
                                                                                                mainQueue]];
});
```

Please note that neither the iPad I tested nor the simulator have any issues about it.
Also the same app on the store, compiled with the past Xcode, seems to have no issue on any device, both according to my tests and on the lack of users feedbacks.
I could not test it on my iPhone 4 as I seem unable to install the app on it from the new Xcode: it complaints the iPhone is busy when I try to install it.

Has anyone had a similar problem and knows how to fix it?

Comment: Please provide a backtrace of all threads ("bt all" in lldb) to see where that is blocked.

Comment: Sorry, I have never used this tool so far, where do I execute this command? Thanks.

Comment: lldb is the debugger.  When you debug a process in Xcode, it will usually open up in a view in the lower right corner.

Comment: I think you mean where the logs of the app appear, as the other panel seems not editable. When I enter that command nothing happens.

Comment: Also it does not show the (lldb) prompt as in the instructions. How do I enter that mode?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/support/technical/debugging

Comment: Basically it seems even lldb is stuck.

Comment: Of course I already submitted the bug, but it would the first time I get some result by that means.

Comment: Yet now it seems gone by itself. At least in a way that there is no way to reproduce it.

Comment: Unfortunately now the same problem seems to appear everywhere. At least since the latest Xcode iteration. If I pause the process I see it hangs at: libsystem_kernel.dylib`semaphore_wait_trap:

Comment: If you pause the process, it isn't hung.  It's paused.  If you continue the process, that thread will continue whenever that semaphore fires

Comment: Strangely the issue fixed again by itself. That thing seems a mad hat.

Answer (score 0):

Wipe the device and restore from backup.

Comment: Thanks, in fact this did not happen any longer.