# NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration hangs

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsurlsession

Very similar to the issue described here:
[sessionWithConfiguration freezing iOS 8 iPhone 4S on new Xcode 6.0.1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26002518/sessionwithconfiguration-freezing-ios-8-iphone-4s-on-new-xcode-6-0-1)

I have a NSURLSession that i create using backgroundConfigurationWithIdentifier: method (in ios8).

If i create a few hundred downloads, then the app freezes randomly on either `[NSURLSession* invalidateAndCancel]` or on the `NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:backgroundConfiguration];`

If i restart the device, this goes away. This is only replicable if i queue a few hundred downloads and then send the '`invalidateAndCancel`' message.
**UPDATE** If i queue only a handful of downloads on the session then this works. So it seems that the NSURLSession can't handle that many tasks queued, even when you provide your own NSOperationQueue.

Comment: did u managed to find a solution for this  ??

Comment: @Mr.G As stated in the update, I handled this by ensuring I have a low (around 10 ) number of tasks in the background session.